# Typescript is throwing "error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1." error

Tags: typescript, ts-node

I get this error, when setting module to common js in tsconfig.json file:

```
"module": "commonjs"
```

My Function is like this:

```
function say(message, options: MessageOptions = {}) {
  talk(userId, message, options);
}

say('Hello');
```

The problem goes away if I set module to ES2020. But, then I get other error:

> Using import outside of module error.

Code in the file where I get this error:

```
import './lib/env';
import app from './bootstrap/server';
export default app;
```

My eslint file

```
module.exports = {


root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
  },
  ignorePatterns: ['node_modules/'],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020, // Allows for the parsing of modern ECMAScript features
    sourceType: 'module', // Allows for the use of imports
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended', // Uses the recommended rules from the @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
    'prettier/@typescript-eslint', // Uses eslint-config-prettier to disable ESLint rules from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin that would conflict with prettier
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'no-var': 'error',
    'max-len': 0,
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: [
        '**/__tests__/*.{j,t}s?(x)',
        '**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.{j,t}s?(x)',
      ],
      env: {
        jest: true,
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

My tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules",".vscode", ".idea"]
}
```

Comment: You can fix this by adding export statement to the function, but are you sure your function definition is correct?  I mean the first argument looks strange.

Comment: I'm still getting that error, even after using export in the file.

Comment: It's not strange except it has no type. The reason it throws the error is that it's expecting 2 arguments, since neither of them are optional.

Comment: @MikeS. Is second parameter not optional in function `say`? It gave me same error when using:
functino say(message, options?: MessageOptions)

Comment: The second parameter indeed has to be optional. Even if you give it a default value.

Comment: Or else it always expects 2 parameters, message and options.

Comment: Try to create a reproducible example of your problem, for example on stackblitz. If the second parameter is made optional, `say('Hello')` should work as intended.

Comment: @RafaelRocha, So how do I make it optional? I will update my question with my full function.

Comment: @MikeS. Its working in stackblitz perfectly. I don't know what going on in here. Should I share my tsconfig.json file. Or could it be my typescript linter package?

Comment: in the function: `function sayHello(message: string, options?: MessageOptions = {})`

Comment: @RafaelRocha I get error when trying to use ?: with default assignment.

Comment: please share more details on your code, the linting and tsconfig please :)

Comment: @RafaelRocha added config files.